# Invalidating WinUI/UWP BitmapImage cache

Tags: uwp, winui-3, winui

I'm trying to work out a way of invalidating the cache for a BitmapImage. My suspicion is that under the covers, this is implemented by something akin to a dictionary of path to memory stream, and when I recreate the `BitmapImage` with the same path it's just reading the cached stream without noticing that the image on the file system has changed.

I know that I can work around this with code like this:

```
var bi = new BitmapImage();
if(!initialLoad)
   bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bi.UriSource = new Uri(absolutePath);
return bi;
```

The problem with the above is that it always ignores the cache and loads it fresh. What I'd like is for a way to invalidate the image cache when the image changes, but then keep the image in the cache.

The image is being loaded from the file system.

Is that possible?

Comment: Do you have a reproducing sample? Where are you loading the image from?

Comment: It will be better if you could share more detailed information about the behavior you are getting. Like how do you load the image and where does the image come from.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT it's being loaded from disk. The behaviour is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.createoptions?view=winrt-22000

Comment: Maybe I did not make myself clear. I want to know did this(using the `IgnoreImageCache` option ) cause a problem for you like it failed to load the image?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT sorry if my question is unclear - I say that using `IgnoreImageCache` gets around it, but it also doesn't cache the loaded image. I want the image cache to be invalidated when the image on the filesystem changes.

Comment: Nothing will reload the image when the file changes. You'll have to use some component for that like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39743509/403671

Answer (score 0):

> What I'd like is for a way to invalidate the image cache when the image changes, but then keep the image in the cache.

I have to say the answer is no, there are no such options that could directly do that. Currently, the API only provides two options for the image cache - **cached** or **ignored** so there is no way to achieve the behavior you want. As @Simon Mourier mentioned, the only workaround is that you might need to handle the content change event manually and then change the image by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me Roy. Just so I'm clear, I don't want this to automatically reload the image when it changes, but I'll ask my question in a slightly different way. When specifying `IgnoreImageCache', will the newer version of the bitmap be cached for subsequent use? I.e. does IgnoreImageCache only ignore for creation but then update the cache once loaded?

Comment: @Sam No, when you set the IgnoreImageCache, no image will be cached.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way at all to replace an image that is already in the cache? That seems like a massive design shortfall.

Comment: @Sam First, if you are setting the `BitmapCreateOptions` as `IgnoreImageCache`, not image will be cached.  Second,when you do not set this, the old image will be cached. 
If you want to cache a new image, you need to set a new source, and the `BitmapImage` will cache the new source.